# How to make notification popup in admin Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, messages, adminnotification

how to make notification popup in admin as a module.
[image]

Any help? Thank in advance.

Comment: Check Magento_AdminNotification module you will get your answer

Comment: @Hiren I know, but I don't understand all of theme.

Comment: https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/add-custom-admin-system-message/

Comment: @RkRathod please read carefully, your refer not guide make notification.

Comment: @Pritam Info 24 can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Create the below files in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Notification/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageList">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="messages" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="Notification" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Notification\Model\Notification</item>
           </argument>
       </arguments>
   </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Notification/Model/Notification.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Notification\Model;
class Notification implements \Magento\Framework\Notification\MessageInterface
{
    public function getIdentity()
    {
        // Unique message identity
        return 'identity';
    }
    public function isDisplayed()
    {
        // Return true to show your message, false to hide it
        return true;
    }
    public function getText()
    {
        // Your Custom Message here.
        return "Notification Add Successfully";
    }
    public function getSeverity()
    {
        //Available Message Types
        // SEVERITY_CRITICAL
        // SEVERITY_MAJOR
        // SEVERITY_MINOR
        // SEVERITY_NOTICE
        return self::SEVERITY_CRITICAL;
    }
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: are you try this, your code makes system message, not popup message.